# How to get integers until \n for n number of lines

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, input, stl

My input :
the first input is number of lines the input will contain

```
5
7 3 29 0
3 4 3 
2 3 4 55 5
2 3
1 2 33 4 5
```

My issue is how can I store them in vector of vector..?

My concept..

```
.
.
.
cin>>n;
vector<vector<int>>vec;
while(n--)
{
    vector<int>vec2;
    for(**Getting input until the line**){
    vec2.emplace_back(input);}
    vec.emplace_back(vec2)
}
```

I need to implement that getting input till the line. For this I thought of getting the input as string and storing the values in vector vec2 using **strtok** after converting it to c_string... But I need to know whether there is any efficient way I can overcome this problem..

Comment: Your idea is actually pretty accurate, as you don't exactly know how many numbers are in a line. For a beginner it would be far easier to do what you wanted and get the whole string - and then iterate over it.

The general answer to iterating over a string by delimiters can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, YMMV.

1. Read each line into a string.
2. Use `istringstream` to extract the integers from the string, into a vector.
3. After string is processed, `push_back` the vector into the outer vector.

```
    unsigned int rows;  
    std::cin >> rows;  
    std::string text_row;  
    for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < rows; ++i)  
    {  
        std::getline(cin, text_row);  
        std::istringstream numbers_stream(text_row);  
        std::vector<int>  row_data;  
        int number;  
        while (numbers_stream >> number)  
        {  
            row_data.push_back(number);  
        }  
        vec.push_back(row_data);  
    }
```

Comment: Use ```emplace_back()``` good practice !

Comment: If ```emplace_back``` have advantage over ```push_back```  then why ```push_back``` is still in the game? Does ```push_back``` have any unique feature..?

Comment: Small nitpick - I would move `getline()` into the `for` loop condition, in case it fails: `for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < rows && std::getline(cin, text_row); ++i)` I would also change the outer `push_back()` to use `std::move()` to avoid an unnecessary copy: `vec.push_back(std::move(row_data));` Or, like Zeros implied, use `emplace_back()` instead: `auto &row_data = vec.emplace_back(); while (numbers_stream >> number) { row_data.push_back(number); }`